# How come css animations change z-index?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

Why is it that the animation changes the z-index?

If you look at the jsfiddle, you'll see the red image is on top but if you comment out the animation, the blue image is on top. How can I get the blue image to always be on top even with the animation?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wquLz46/16/)

HTML

```
<img class="blue" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/0037ff">
<img class="red" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0010">
```

CSS

```
.red {
  -webkit-animation-name: red;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: red;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.blue {
  transform: translate(30%);
}

@keyframes red {
  from {
    transform: translate(50%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements in HTML are positioned on the z-axis according to their [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

By default a page has 1 stacking context – the HTML element – and all children of a stacking context are positioned according to their DOM order.

However, a new stacking context can be created on an element when certain CSS properties are applied. Properties such as `position: absolute` or `position: relative` are commonly used to create new stacking contexts, which is why you are able to position them on the z-axis with `z-index`. When a new stacking context is created, it is positioned above the parent stacking context by default.

`transform` is another CSS property that will create a new stacking context (since you can transform an element on the z-axis). Since the `.blue` element has a `transform` but the `.red` element doesn't when you comment out the animation, it gets a new stacking context which defaults to above the parent stacking context (which includes the `.red` element).

So to get the `.blue` box to always stay on top, you'll need to add `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` to it.

```
.blue {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(30%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Animations [reset the z-index](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid--webdesign-4867#highlighter_399912).

So what you probably have to do is give the red image a z-index of 0 and the blue image a z-index of 1.

Comment: Adding a z-index didn't do anything.

Comment: Did you also set z-index on @keyframes, both from and to? Because this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/0wquLz46/23/

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put a z-index value on `.blu`?

try this:

```
.blue{
z-index: 999;
transform: translate(30%);
}
```

Comment: Adding z-index doesn't help

Comment: i see, it works only in firefox, sorry man.

Comment: UPDATE: add a position: `relative` to `.blue` and try it