# Video z-index transform rotate abnormal behavior

Tags: html, css, video

I have a scene. There are various components on the `canvas`. There are `videos`, `pictures` and common `materials`.

As shown below, the `video` (the black one) will block the image below, but the 'z-index'of the image is 2, higher than the 'z-index' of the video is 1

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-rotate {
  position: relative;
  width: 211px;
  height: 375px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.css-pic {
  /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 43.07px;
  top: 175.78px;
  width: 124.8px;
  height: 83.2px;
  /* background: red; */
}
.css-video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 210.94px;
  height: 375px;
  background: blue;
}
.css-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.css-static {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="css-wrap">
        <div class="css-rotate">
          <div class="css-overflow">
            <div class="css-pic">
              <div class="css-height">
                <img class="css-static" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43111ebfc98a0b559c4a1dc31b6e39f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-video">
              <div class="css-height">
                <video class="css-static" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="true" x5-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x5-video-player-fullscreen="true" preload="auto">
                  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
                </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking up some data, it is found that it may be related to the context caused by transform, but after a little modification, it is even more confusing.

There are at least three ways I can make pictures work:

**1. Remove the overflow: hidden of the parent (but this is not removable, which is confusing)**

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-rotate {
  position: relative;
  width: 211px;
  height: 375px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.css-pic {
  /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 43.07px;
  top: 175.78px;
  width: 124.8px;
  height: 83.2px;
  /* background: red; */
}
.css-video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 210.94px;
  height: 375px;
  background: blue;
}
.css-overflow {
  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.css-static {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="css-wrap">
        <div class="css-rotate">
          <div class="css-overflow">
            <div class="css-pic">
              <div class="css-height">
                <img class="css-static" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43111ebfc98a0b559c4a1dc31b6e39f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-video">
              <div class="css-height">
                <video class="css-static" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="true" x5-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x5-video-player-fullscreen="true" preload="auto">
                  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
                </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. Change the angle of rotate to a small angle such as 0 or 20 (does this mean that it may not be caused by transform?)**

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-rotate {
  position: relative;
  width: 211px;
  height: 375px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.css-pic {
  /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 43.07px;
  top: 175.78px;
  width: 124.8px;
  height: 83.2px;
  /* background: red; */
}
.css-video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 210.94px;
  height: 375px;
  background: blue;
}
.css-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.css-static {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="css-wrap">
        <div class="css-rotate">
          <div class="css-overflow">
            <div class="css-pic">
              <div class="css-height">
                <img class="css-static" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43111ebfc98a0b559c4a1dc31b6e39f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-video">
              <div class="css-height">
                <video class="css-static" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="true" x5-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x5-video-player-fullscreen="true" preload="auto">
                  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
                </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**3. If you delete the video element or display: none, you will find that the display level is correct (does that mean the problem lies in the video element)**

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-rotate {
  position: relative;
  width: 211px;
  height: 375px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.css-pic {
  /* backface-visibility: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 43.07px;
  top: 175.78px;
  width: 124.8px;
  height: 83.2px;
  /* background: red; */
}
.css-video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 210.94px;
  height: 375px;
  background: blue;
}
.css-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.css-static {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="css-wrap">
        <div class="css-rotate">
          <div class="css-overflow">
            <div class="css-pic">
              <div class="css-height">
                <img class="css-static" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43111ebfc98a0b559c4a1dc31b6e39f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-video">
              <div class="css-height">
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After these three guesses, does the mixed effect of video, absolute and rotate lead to the abnormal performance of 'z-index'?

I hope someone can give me an answer.
Thanks.

Comment: test your code on Fiferox and you will get your answer because you will not have the same output as in Chrome. This is most likely a bug in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

There you go just set the `z-index` of video to `-1` so that i goes behind all your content and set the above context `z-index` as per req.

> Here is updated snippet

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.css-rotate {
  position: relative;
  width: 211px;
  height: 375px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.css-pic {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 124.8px;
    height: 83.2px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.css-video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 210.94px;
  height: 375px;
  background: blue;
}
.css-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.css-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.css-static {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="css-wrap">
        <div class="css-rotate">
          <div class="css-overflow">
            <div class="css-pic">
              <div class="css-height">
                <img class="css-static" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/43111ebfc98a0b559c4a1dc31b6e39f6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="css-video">
              <div class="css-height">
                <video class="css-static" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="true" x5-playsinline="" x5-video-player-type="h5" x5-video-player-fullscreen="true" preload="auto">
                  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
                </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And also i set the image to center of `video`

Comment: thank you for your advice.the zindex -1 can really solve the case.but unfortunate.
This demo is simplified from the actual project，zindex for video is not always set to - 1

Comment: In terms of performance, it can be solved. But it can't solve my doubts. What caused this performance

Comment: @Qyellow Dear The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.*Note:*z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-css-position-absolute-brings-the-overlay-element-to-the-front

Comment: This explanation is a possibility that I have considered. As mentioned above, a small angle of rotate, such as 20 or 40, can display the picture normally. This is where I wonder

Comment: @Qyellow Opps i got it here is the answer to your question [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883309/how-come-css-animations-change-z-index), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate) , Link 2 will be more precised

Comment: maybe not, i read link2 yestoday, his solution is to rotate at the wrap layer, as I did, and my 3 demo shows if i hidden the video, it shows right